# Pivot in FluentNhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, pivot

I have a table structure as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MessageParameters 
(
    SequenceId              int                 IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MessageQueueId          int                 NOT NULL,
    ParameterName           varchar(50)         NOT NULL,
    ParameterValue          varchar(300)        NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_MessageParameters PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(SequenceId)
)

CREATE TABLE MessageQueue
(
    SequenceId              int                 IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MessageType             int                 NOT NULL,
    [Status]                int                 DEFAULT(0) NOT NULL,
    Created                 datetime            DEFAULT(GETDATE()) NOT NULL,
    Modified                datetime            DEFAULT(GETDATE()) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_MessageQueue PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(SequenceId)
)
```

What I want to do is use subclassing based on MessageType for my object model.  This is straightforward enough, but I would like to pivot the collection of parameters into actual properties on my subclass.

For instance, I have the (sub)class ActivationEmail

```
public class ActivationEmail : MessageBase
{
    //shared properties are member of base class

    public string Param1 {get; set;}
    public string Param2 {get; set;}
    public string Param3 {get; set;}
}
```

Will result in data in my MessageParameters table above like this

```
ParameterName                              ParameterValue
------------------------------------------ ---------------------------------
Param1                                     value1
Param2                                     value2
Param3                                     value3
```

I understand that I could have a List as part of the object for the params and have the properties (Param1, Param2, etc) auto add/update/retrieve the data in this list, but I'm hoping for something handled within the mappings themselves.

Comment: For now, my parameters are stored in an `IDictionary<TEnum, string>`

Comment: I am 99.999999% sure there is no mapping that can do that. Think of how difficult that would be to translate back and forth. Also, wouldn't you lose the ParameterName column? or would that be considered the property name?

Comment: the name of the property is the ParameterName field